# How do I share bluetooth keyboard with iPhone and iMac without re-pairing every time?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

This may be an impossible request, but I'm looking for some way, or some software to install, that lets me choose which device I want to type on at a particular moment.

For example: Most of the time I am typing on my iMac. But when a text message comes in, or I want to type a long password on my iPhone, I want to use my apple bluetooth keyboard to type on my iPhone for a bit, and then switch back to typing on my iMac.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Can you pair Mac AND iPad with same Apple Wireless Keyboard?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/23924/14994) - [Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23927/14994)

Comment: I'm not sure you can without getting a second keyboard. I normally turn off Bluetooth on whichever device I don't want using the keyboard.

Comment: Not a duplicate because I don't want to pair with both. I'm looking for a software solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ikeyboard in the mac app store

Comment: Perfect, this is a great app!

Answer (score 1):

While a device (iMac or iPhone) can have a number of peripherals attached it it, a peripheral can only be attached to one device at a time. So you will need to re-pair it every time.

Comment: That is a good point. The problem is more with the bluetooth hardware vs. the Mac (or iOS) software.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this keyboard from Logitech that is a hardware solution to do what you want.

[This keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/keyboards/keyboard/devices/Wireless-Solar-Keyboard-K760-for-Mac?wt.mc_id=global_redirect_news_Wireless-Solar-Keyboard-K760-for-Mac) is a MAC keyboard that can be programed to switch devices with one button.

Comment: Thanks, i saw that this morning too and I think I might get it! iKeyboard has been working out well, too.